# 128K Mac without signatures inside

Tags: mac

I have a 128K Mac with an odd thing about it.  It has **no** signatures inside the case.  Every other 128K and even most 512Ks that I've seen have all the team signatures inside but, this one has doesn't. I'm pretty sure the rear shell hasn't been replaced.

Has anyone else ever seen a 128K without any signatures in it?

Comment: I think this would be a far better fit for https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ - not sure it's strictly off-topic here, but I'm sure you will find more expertise there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com .

Comment: You have a replaced case back.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the signatures were only on the initial run of the 128K Macs.

I dug this up from [DigiBarn Weird Stuff](http://www.digibarn.com/collections/weirdstuff/mac-case-signatures/)

> These signatures were molded into the case and included here
>   (gradually disappearing) for several generations of Macs through to
>   the SE

And from the [Obsolete Computer Museum](http://www.obsoletecomputermuseum.org/mac128/)..

> The first Macs had only 128k RAM and used single-sided, 400k floppy
>   drives. The signatures of the original Mac designers are molded into
>   the inside back of the case.

It's possible that this may be a latter generation 128K Mac without the signatures.

You also say that you're "pretty sure" the rear shell hasn't been replaced.  However, you didn't say that you were *certain.*  It's entirely possible it was replaced for service at some point.

Comment: The signatures were inside the case of all original Macs (rebranded 128k), Mac 512ke's (I still have 1), and many Apple Mac SE's (I had one with signatures, but sold it).  The signatures were removed from the case mold for the Mac SE/30's.